# All control property change in loop

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm writing a code to apply transparent background to all of my LinkLabel controls. I don't wanna do it with hardcoded label id and repeating the same code.

```
    foreach (Control cType in this.Controls)
    {
      if (cType.GetType() == typeof(LinkLabel))
      {
        LinkLabel linkTemp = cType as LinkLabel;
        Point pos = this.PointToScreen(linkTemp.Location);
        pos = pictureBox1.PointToClient(pos);
        linkTemp.Parent = pictureBox1;
        linkTemp.Location = pos;
        linkTemp.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
      }
    }
```

When I'm trying the above piece of code it make odd numbered buttons to be transparent i.e.

> Button 1 - transparent
>
> Button 2 - NOT
>
> Button 3 - transparent

But while I'm repeating the same code applied on different linklabel ids manually its working fine. What I'm missing here?

Comment: when debugging, what happens when it reaches button2? Is it evaluating as a LinkLabel? It seems like this would be fairly easy to figure out with some simple debugging steps.

Comment: @MikeC. I tried to check the count. i.e. How many times if check is getting triggered. There is no problem. Its returning correct number.

Comment: Right, but have you traced it through for the buttons that are failing and watched it actually apply the transparent color to it? What you're describing is certainly unusual sounding behavior. I would step through for every button and make sure it's behaving as you expect. Beyond that, I'd make the bit inside the foreach a method, and call it manually with the buttons that are failing and see what happens.

Comment: @MikeC. nice suggestion. let me try.

Comment: @MikeC. Somehow the control count is always returning less than actual number. My previous checking is not matching now. I have 5 linklabels on my form but its only returning 3.

Comment: After a more deep investigation what I found that, if I change the order in FormDesigner.cs file it also changes the order of transparent buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an inevitable side-effect of you changing the Parent property of the control.  That *modifies* the Controls collection since the LinkLabel is moved from the form's Controls collection to the pictureBox1.Controls collection.  Modifying a collection while iterating it normally generates an InvalidOperationException but this was not done for the Controls collection.

You need to solve this by iterating the collection backwards.  Like this:

```
for (int ix = this.Controls.Count-1; ix >= 0; --ix) {
    var linkTemp = this.Controls[ix] as LinkLabel;
    if (linkTemp == null) continue;
    // etc..
}
```

Some programmers like using Linq, that's okay too but obfuscates the issue a bit and isn't nearly as efficient.  Key is to make a copy that cannot be affected by modifying the collection:

```
foreach (var linkTemp in this.Controls.OfType<LinkLabel>().ToList()) {
    // etc..
}
```

Comment: Is your first loop supposed to be `foreach` instead of `for`?

Answer (score -2):

You can use this 'odd' construction:

```
int i = 1;
foreach (LinkLabel item in this.Controls.OfType<LinkLabel>())
{
    if ((i = 1 - i) == 0)
    {
        LinkLabel linkTemp = cType as LinkLabel;
        Point pos = this.PointToScreen(linkTemp.Location);
        pos = pictureBox1.PointToClient(pos);
        linkTemp.Parent = pictureBox1;
        linkTemp.Location = pos;
        linkTemp.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }
}
```

**Some tips for code formatting**

Change

```
if (cType.GetType() == typeof(LinkLabel))
```

to

```
if (cType is LinkLabel)
```

Change

```
foreach (Control cType in this.Controls)
{
  if (cType.GetType() == typeof(LinkLabel))
  {
    LinkLabel linkTemp = cType as LinkLabel;
    Point pos = this.PointToScreen(linkTemp.Location);
    pos = pictureBox1.PointToClient(pos);
    linkTemp.Parent = pictureBox1;
    linkTemp.Location = pos;
    linkTemp.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
  }
}
```

to

```
foreach (LinkLabel linkTemp in this.Controls.OfType<LinkLabel>())
{
    Point pos = this.PointToScreen(linkTemp.Location);
    pos = pictureBox1.PointToClient(pos);
    linkTemp.Parent = pictureBox1;
    linkTemp.Location = pos;
    linkTemp.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
}
```

Comment: while this is nice suggestions, it does not in any way answer the question.